# Summation of elements of a Set [Notation]

Tags: notation, summation

Is there any compact Notation to express the summation of all the elements of a set?

Comment: I think $\Sigma(X)$ is acceptable. However, I would view $X$ as a multiset. That way, $\Sigma(X \oplus Y) = \Sigma(X)+\Sigma(Y),$ where $\oplus$ is the sum of multisets.

Comment: $\sum_{s \in S}{s}$, where S is the set and s are the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you don't speak of a summation of elements of a *set*, but of elements of a *family*. A set can't have repeated elements, a family is "indexed" (you could represent it as a function from some index set to your universe).

So if a family $\mathcal F$ is defined as

$$
    \mathcal F = (X_i : i\in\mathcal I)
$$

then its sum $\sum\mathcal F$ is

$$
\sum\mathcal F = \sum_{i\in\mathcal I}X_i
$$

Answer (score 2):

If $I$ is your set, then $$\sum_{i\in I} i$$

Answer (score 2):

I've often seen the following notation. For a set $X$:
$$\sum_{x \in X} x$$